# Scripting IvyGen with Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am quite new to Blender and scripting in it. I am looking for a way to use IvyGen in script, but found no tutorials. I checked the Info panel in Blender, but it only says

```
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.curve.ivy_gen(updateIvy=False)
```

whenever I add an ivy. I am expecting to see more parameters (to control the location, the appearance, etc.) than just it. Indeed, I've tried to run these commands on Blender Python console, but just got:

```
{'PASS_THROUGH'}
```

So I am wondering if you could help me understand how scripting is actually working with ivy_gen and maybe some guide of how I can get started with it.

Comment: This should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the ivy_gen operator with specific values for all the parameters you would later edit in the context menu:

```
bpy.ops.curve.ivy_gen(
    maxIvyLength         = 1,
    primaryWeight        = 0.5,
    randomWeight         = 0.2,
    gravityWeight        = 1,
    adhesionWeight       = 0.1,
    branchingProbability = 0.05,
    leafProbability      = 0.35,
    ivySize              = 0.02,
    ivyLeafSize          = 0.02,
    ivyBranchSize        = 0.001,
    maxFloatLength       = 0.5,
    maxAdhesionDistance  = 1,
    randomSeed           = 0,
    maxTime              = 0,
    growLeaves           = True,
    updateIvy            = False
)
```

To fully automate this, all you need to do prior to calling this operator is to place the 3D cursor where you want your ivy to start growing:

`bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (x,y,z)`

And to also select the object you want to grow your ivy on:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects['MyObject'].select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active             = bpy.context.scene.objects['MyObject']
```